# How to draw/ plot graphs in python?

Tags: python-3.x, graph, charts, rating-system

I have some float data for an entity from 0 to 5, but i want to show them in graph like

```
price 3.6
___________
look 3.8
_____________
user friendly 4.3
__________________
reliability 2.3
______
```

so as there any package in python or help, or suggestion please ?

Comment: You shouldn't need any package for such simple ascii graphics -- write a small program (shouldn't be any more than a few lines of code)

Comment: @JohnColeman but this is just exmple, i want to show that data with pretty charts, the lines under every value is meant to be chart line. like bar chart...

Comment: I see -- though I will still keep my answer since it is still nice to have a quick prototype for programming purposes. See the link I gave.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want are simple bar charts made with underscores then something like this could be done:

```
def display(nums,unit = 0.2):
    pairs = zip(("price","look","user friendly", "reliability"),nums)
    for (label,num) in pairs:
        print(label,round(num,1))
        print("_" * round(num/unit))
```

typical output:

```
>>> display((3.6,3.8,4.3,2.3))
price 3.6
__________________
look 3.8
___________________
user friendly 4.3
_____________________
reliability 2.3
___________
```

If you want more sophisticated graphics, look into [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/)